# Hooking on to lid events as non-root

Tags: non-root-user, laptop, events

Is there a way for a non-root user to hook a script on to laptop lid events (ie. opening and closing)?

Comment: How about `sudo`? I used `sudo` in my laptop several years ago for lid and additional buttons (vol up/down, stop/play, brightness) in KDE environment.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk, how did you access the x session from root?

Comment: @Toothrot I'm not sure that you'd want/need to use `root` to manage your x session. The xsession should be running as the logged in user, so they should be able to change it themselves as they please.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take these notifications via acp event hooks https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/acpid